# How-to convert real number into List of its digits?

Tags: functions

How could I convert a real number into a `List` of its digits in Mathematica?

Example:

> 8.168643234

Desired output:

> {8,1,6,8,6,4,3,2,3,4}

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `First[RealDigits[x]]`?

Comment: @bbgodfrey thank you! I only just started working with Mathematica and I find it all brand new. I am a software engineer. I am looking to learn more about wolfram language!

Comment: @MichaelE2 using your example I am not getting the output that I am looking for :s, thank you for trying!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you enter a number with a decimal point like:

```
x = 8.168643234;
```

you are telling *Mathematica* that this is a [machine precision](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html) number. You can see this with:

```
Precision[x]
(* MachinePrecision *)
```

This means that the internal representation of the number is not exactly what you entered, but instead is the nearest machine real. `RealDigits` shows you the digits in the actual value of `x`:

```
First[RealDigits[x]]
(* {8, 1, 6, 8, 6, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9} *)
```

If you want to get the exact output in the question, you will need to either specify the precision of the number:

```
x = 8.168643234`10;

First[RealDigits[x]]
(* {8, 1, 6, 8, 6, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4} *)
```

or enter it as an exact (infinite precision) number:

```
x = 8168643234*10^-9;

First[RealDigits[x]]
(* {8, 1, 6, 8, 6, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time answering my question. I appreciate your effort!

Comment: @user1989, no problem. By the way it is usual here to wait a while before accepting an answer, so as not to discourage others from posting other, potentially better, answers. 24 hours is good as it gives the whole globe a chance to contribute.

Comment: I will keep that in mind! My apologies, reading through rules of this forum!

Comment: @user1989, No apology necessary! It's not a rule, just a good tactic to get the best out of the site :-)