# Calculate the value of a number as if it were represented in binary

Tags: numerical-value, number-representation

I want to design a function that receives a number in binary, $110.11$ for example, and transform it to decimal.
I would like to transform it into a list: {1,1,0,1,1}. However I have a lot of problems with approximation and all that stuff. I saw [How-to convert real number into List of its digits?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72311/how-to-convert-real-number-into-list-of-its-digits) but it didn't help. I was planning to separate the number into its Integer Part and its Fractional Part and then use that function to get {1,1,0} and {1,1}. I have functions that translate integer numbers to decimal: {1,1,0} to 6; and fractional to decimal: {0.11} to 0.75. I only need the function to get the digits into a list.
Any hints?

This transforms Integer binary number (given by a list) to decimal

```
BinEnt[x_] := Module[{i, s},
  s = 0;
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[x], i++, s = s + x[[i]]*2^(Length[x] - i)];
  s]
```

This transforms a fractional number of the form 0.abcd... in binary (given by list) to decimal:

```
BinDec[x_] := Module[{i, s},
  s = 0;
  For[i = 1, i <= Length[x], i++, s = s + x[[i]]*2^(-i)];
  s]
```

Comment: What is the expected output? `{1,1,0,1,1}` translates to `27` but your number is `6.75`. Please clarify.

Comment: Well, I was planning to separate the number into its Integer Part and its Fractional Part and then use that function to get {1,1,0} and {1,1}. I have functions that translate integer numbers to decimal: {1,1,0} to 6; and fractional to decimal: {0.11} to 0.75. I only need the function to get the digits into a list

Answer (score 2):

Okay, after the fifth reading, I think I understand. What you want is to get a number and then do three things:

- Assume that all of the decimal digits of the number are actually binary (i.e. 0 or 1)
- Interpret this number as binary
- Convert this assumed binary representation to a (implicitly decimal) number

If that's true, then:

**New**

```
BinaryToDecimal[num_] := FromDigits[RealDigits[num, 10], 2]
```

**Previous**

```
BinaryToDecimal[num_] :=
  With[
    {decimalDigits = RealDigits[num]},
    With[
      {binaryDigitPair = TakeDrop[decimalDigits[[1]], decimalDigits[[2]]]},
      Plus @@ MapAt[#/(2^Length[binaryDigitPair[[2]]]) &, FromDigits[#, 2] & /@ binaryDigitPair, 2]]]
```

**Commentary requested by OP**

We need to get the digits, and RealDigits is our friend there. This change of representation also kind of strips the numeric interpretation, which we need to do since our interpretation of the input is different than Mathematica's.

It would be nice if we could just apply FromDigits, but then it'd be interpreted.... wait, let's actually try that:

```
FromDigits[RealDigits[110.11, 10], 2]
(* 27/4 *)
```

Well, there you go!

```
BinaryToDecimal[num_] := FromDigits[RealDigits[num, 10], 2]
```

What was I thinking?!?!

But anyway, I didn't think about using FromDigits directly, and thought I needed to apply it to the integer and fractional parts separately. So, I used TakeDrop to get those two lists. Now I could apply FromDigits, but since the second one represents a fraction, I need to do something so I don't end up with just an integer. So, I divided the number FromDigits gave me by the appropriate power of 2.

Comment: That is correct, thanks. Could you briefly explain what the function does, as Im not familiar to many of these functions?

Comment: @PedroGarcía it could be worth taking the time to break apart the function and see what the sequence of evaluation does while looking at the documentation. A quick and visual way to see what a code does is given in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29340/86543). The benefit of engaging in trying to understand the pieces of the code yourself is that you are more likely to remember the functions involved and you might be curious to see other functions in the examples of the documentation and in the "See also" section.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to get confused around the semantics here.

> I want to design a function that receives a number in binary

You don't receive numeric arguments in a particular format like decimal or binary. You receive them as they are internally represented by Mathematica. You will need to come up with a format for your arguments that represents binary. Let's defer that for a moment and deal with getting your digits. So, let's assume we just get a number into this function that you want to define:

```
BinaryDigits[num_?NumberQ] := RealDigits[num, 2]
```

So, this functionality is built in with RealDigits. Here are some examples:

```
BinaryDigits[3]
(* {{1, 1}, 2} *)

BinaryDigits[3.5]
(* {{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 2} *)
```

Notice a couple of things. First, the output from RealDigits gives you a flat list of all digits and a number that indicates how many precede the decimal point. That's not the way you specified your desired output, but without this your output is ambiguous. If you really just want the digit list, then just take the first part. Second, notice all of those zeros. The input was a finite-precision number, which Mathematica typically stores with the equivalent of about 15 decimal digits.

Okay, so back to the input format for a binary number. One way to do this would be to take in strings. You might want to add some validation to the following (be careful with leading decimal points, for example).

```
BinaryDigits[num_String] :=
  With[
    {digitlists = (ToExpression@*Characters)[StringSplit[num, "."]]},
    {Join @@ digitlists, Length@digitlists[[1]]}]
```

Examples:

```
BinaryDigits["110.11"]
(* {{1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, 3} *)

BinaryDigits["10101"]
(* {{1, 0, 1, 0, 1}, 5} *)

BinaryDigits["0.1"]
(* {{0, 1}, 1} *)
```

Now, that's just an example. We need more clarity about exactly what you want your input format to be.

**UPDATE**

Sigh. You've changed the problem. Okay, so your representation of binary is two lists. Fortunately, we can do the inverse of RealDigits with FromDigits:

```
BinaryDigitsToDecimal[intDigits : {(0 | 1) ...}, fracDigits : {(0 | 1) ...}] := 
  FromDigits[{Join[intDigits, fracDigits], Length@intDigits}, 2]

BinaryDigitsToDecimal[{1, 0, 1}, {1, 1}] // N
(* 5.75 *)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help, I learnt a couple things, but I want to receive the number as a number (redudant but I think you get me)

Comment: I assume what you mean is the you want your function to output a number. See my update.

Comment: I would strongly suggest that you edit your post. Your title says "Transforming a number to a list" but you actually want to transform lists into a number. And your explanation of what you want is very confusing. It would be better if you just explained what you want your inputs and outputs to be.

Comment: I want to introduce 110.11 and get 6.75. I dont want to input lists, I want to use lists to get the result

Comment: It would have been nice if that is what you had said in the first place.